# Uniform continuity on bounded set is bounded for every metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from a subset $E$ of a metric space $X$ to metric space $Y$ and $E$ is bounded in $X$. Is $f(E)$ a bounded subset of $Y$? What if $Y$ is complete metric space?

Well, I have this thought: Suppose $f:\Bbb R_{()}\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ where $\Bbb R_{()}$ has bounded metric. Now let $E=\Bbb R$, then $f(E)$ not bounded even if $E$ bounded and $f$ uniformly continuous.

Am I right?

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I thought this way: $f':\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f'(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous, because for $\epsilon>0$, $\delta=\epsilon$ implies $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|x-y|<\epsilon$. For $f$ as in my post, I have to take $\delta'=\min\{\delta,\frac12\}$ for given $\epsilon$. Is this wrong argument?

Comment: Can you make explicit what is your bounded metric?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ has Euclidean metric $d=||$, and $\Bbb R_{()}$ has metric has metric $\bar{d}(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y),1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are right.